# How can I make specific URL patterns open via a Chrome application shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome

I use Google Chrome Application Shortcuts for a quite a few internal tools hosted as internal websites. Having them pinned as their own icon on the Windows 7 taskbar and not mixed in with the other browsers.

However, if I click on links in web pages, e-mails, etc. that are links into these tools, they open in the standard Chrome browser window, not the application shortcut window.

Is there a way to get Windows 7 or Google Chrome to target specific URL patterns to the application shortcut window instead of a new browser window?

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new application shortcut and then rename it to whatever you like.

Right Click on it and then go properties.

Under the Target section where you see the path to the application add the URL as below.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.bbc.com
```

That should open a new chrome tab with that specific URL.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, which was about opening Chrome apps, not Chrome itself. https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a method here on Edge. Didn't get success myself.

https://geekermag.com/how-to-open-links-in-microsoft-edge-pwas-web-apps/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1222965)